# The loss effects in multitask learning framework

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, multitasking

I have designed a multi-task network where the first layers are shared between two output layers. Through investigating multi-task learning principles, I got to know that there should be a weight scalar parameter such as `alpha` that dampens the two losses outputted from two output layers. My question is about this parameter itself. Does it have effect on the model's final performance? probably yes.

This is the part of my code snippet for computation of losses:

```
...

mtl_loss = (alpha) * loss_1 + (1-alpha) * loss_2
mtl_loss.backward()

...
```

Above, `loss_1` is MSELoss, and `loss_2` is CrossEntropyLoss. As such, picking `alpha=0.9`, I'm getting the following loss values during training steps:

```
[2020-05-03 04:46:55,398 INFO] Step 50/150000; loss_1: 0.90 + loss_2: 1.48 = mtl_loss: 2.43 (RMSE: 2.03, F1score: 0.07); lr: 0.0000001;  29 docs/s;     28 sec
[2020-05-03 04:47:23,238 INFO] Step 100/150000; loss_1: 0.40 + loss_2: 1.27 = mtl_loss: 1.72 (RMSE: 1.38, F1score: 0.07); lr: 0.0000002;  29 docs/s;     56 sec
[2020-05-03 04:47:51,117 INFO] Step 150/150000; loss_1: 0.12 + loss_2: 1.19 = mtl_loss: 1.37 (RMSE: 0.81, F1score: 0.08); lr: 0.0000003;  29 docs/s;     84 sec
[2020-05-03 04:48:19,034 INFO] Step 200/150000; loss_1: 0.04 + loss_2: 1.10 = mtl_loss: 1.20 (RMSE: 0.55, F1score: 0.07); lr: 0.0000004;  29 docs/s;    112 sec
[2020-05-03 04:48:46,927 INFO] Step 250/150000; loss_1: 0.02 + loss_2: 0.96 = mtl_loss: 1.03 (RMSE: 0.46, F1score: 0.08); lr: 0.0000005;  29 docs/s;    140 sec
[2020-05-03 04:49:14,851 INFO] Step 300/150000; loss_1: 0.02 + loss_2: 0.99 = mtl_loss: 1.05 (RMSE: 0.43, F1score: 0.08); lr: 0.0000006;  29 docs/s;    167 sec
[2020-05-03 04:49:42,793 INFO] Step 350/150000; loss_1: 0.02 + loss_2: 0.97 = mtl_loss: 1.04 (RMSE: 0.43, F1score: 0.08); lr: 0.0000007;  29 docs/s;    195 sec
[2020-05-03 04:50:10,821 INFO] Step 400/150000; loss_1: 0.01 + loss_2: 0.94 = mtl_loss: 1.00 (RMSE: 0.41, F1score: 0.08); lr: 0.0000008;  29 docs/s;    223 sec
[2020-05-03 04:50:38,943 INFO] Step 450/150000; loss_1: 0.01 + loss_2: 0.86 = mtl_loss: 0.92 (RMSE: 0.40, F1score: 0.08); lr: 0.0000009;  29 docs/s;    252 sec
```

As training loss shows, it seems that my first network that uses MSELoss converges super fast, while the second network has not been converged yet. `RMSE`, and `F1score` are two metrics that I'm using to track the progress of first, and second network, respectively.

I know that picking the optimal alpha is somewhat experimental, but are there hints to make the process of picking it easier? Specifically, I want the networks being trained in line with each other, not like above that the first network converges super duper fast. Can `alpha` parameter help controlling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that alpha, loss_1 is contributing more to the result and due backpropagation updates weights proportionally to error it improves faster. Try using more equilibrated alpha to balance the performance in both tasks.

You also can try change alpha during training.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My first task is the one that I most care about. It's relatively easier than the second task, though. Could starting with a large alpha (let's say 0.9) and then trying to reduce it after n training steps be helpful at improving task-1? My intuition is that easier task would help improving harder task (MTL principles), thereafter harder task is improved till some point using easier task, it can then help the easier task to get improved. This alpha parameter seems to be useful for this tuning that two tasks learn the most from each other.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I suggest put the large alpha on the most difficult task,if he simple task improves faster it will not contribute with changes to the NN and it will be almost like train only the second task.